# Definición de DRL con tratamiento de listas

Tags: drools

Estoy intentando generar una regla en Drools que permita evaluar lo siguiente:

Tendríamos el objeto item:

```
public class Item {

  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private List<Prop> props;

  // Constructors, getters & setters.
}
```

Y el Props:

```
public class Prop {
  private Integer propId;
  private Integer type;
  private Integer perc;
  private Boolean isValid;
  private Integer propGroupId;

  // Constructosr, getters & setters.
}
```

IMPORTANTE: varias prop pueden tener el mismo propGroupId

La regla tiene que ser del estilo a:

- "Item que tengan los propGroupId 1 y 2"

Pero con las siguientes consideraciones:

- Un solo se tendrán en cuenta los propGroupId asociados a props que sean tipo 3 o 4 y isValid = true.
- Dado que varias prop pueden pertenecer al mismo grupo, no deberán tenerse en cuenta los duplicados.

De forma abstracta, lo que se pretende conseguir es:

- Recibimos un item con una lista de prop.
- Extraemos una lista sin duplicados de propGroupId que pertenezcan a props de tipo 3 o 4 y isValid = true.
- Esta lista de propGroupId tiene que ser igual (en longitud y contenido) a una serie de valores definidos en el DRL (valores 1 y 2).

Answer (score 1):

```
rule "Ejemplo"
when
  Item( $props: props != null )
  List( size > 0 ) from collect( 
    Prop( propGroupId == 1, type in (3, 4), isValid == true ) from $props 
  )
  List( size > 0 ) from collect(
    Prop( propGroupId == 2, type in (3, 4), isValid == true )
  )
then 
  // ...
end
```

En esta regla, usamos `collect` para acumular una lista de Props que nos interesa:

- propGroupId == 1, y el typo sea 3 o 4, y isValid
- propGroupId == 2, y el typo sea 3 o 4, y isValid

La regla solo funciona si tenemos al menos un Prop de cada categoría.

El uso de `collect` también nos proteja en caso de los Props duplicados. No hay diferencia si existen muchos Props en cada categoría o solo uno: la regla funciona lo mismo y sólo se realiza una vez.